# How to hide secret image inside a video using python?

Tags: python, image, video, steganography

I want to embed two images in a short video by using python language. It is like hiding those two images inside the video and then decrypting to get the secret images back.
I have taken a video input of 7 seconds and fragmented it into frames. Now, I want to hide the two images in these frames using the LSB technique. Then I want to recompile the frames to make the video that hides two images.
Please if anyone can suggest how to do this in python language.

Comment: Have you searched this site and/or google for (video) lsb steganography? It should be trivial to get an idea for methods. Then if you have a more specific question about implementing such an algorithm, you could ask here.

Comment: Yes, and I have got an idea of how lsb works when we hide an image inside an image and text inside a video. But I am not able to figure out how to use this in hiding an image inside a video. If you happen to have any resources that can help, please share @Reti43